# Ignore Text between XML tag

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing

```
""" test.xml

<xyz>
      <pqr>
        <abc><a href="data:text/html;charset=utf-8,base64,JTNjc2NyaXB0JTNlYWxlcnQoIlhTUyIpO2hpc3RvcnkuYmFjaygpOyUzYy9zY3JpcHQlM2UiPjwvYT4=</abc>
      </pqr>
      <pqr>
        <abc><iframe src="data:text/html;charset=utf-8,base64,JTNjc2NyaXB0JTNlYWxlcnQoIlhTUyIpO2hpc3RvcnkuYmFjaygpOyUzYy9zY3JpcHQlM2UiPjwv</abc>
      </pqr>
<xyz>

""""
```

when i use this XML file and parse in python then it shows error(not well formed) . How can i parse this xml file or any other method to get the data from this file.

Comment: You should format code by putting four spaces before each line. You can also select it and click the `{}` button. More helpful tips at the [Markdown Editing Help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the xml first and use cdata to enclose not well formatted xml

example:

```
<xyz>
      <pqr>
        <abc><![CDATA[<a href="data:text/html;charset=utf-8,base64,JTNjc2NyaXB0JTNlYWxlcnQoIlhTUyIpO2hpc3RvcnkuYmFjaygpOyUzYy9zY3JpcHQlM2UiPjwvYT4=]]></abc>
      </pqr>
      <pqr>
        <abc><![CDATA[<iframe src="data:text/html;charset=utf-8,base64,JTNjc2NyaXB0JTNlYWxlcnQoIlhTUyIpO2hpc3RvcnkuYmFjaygpOyUzYy9zY3JpcHQlM2UiPjwv]]></abc>
      </pqr>
<xyz>
```

see: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp

After this you can just use python xml parser

Answer (score 1):

The `<xyz>` tag is not balanced (there are two opening tags) and the `test.xml` line is spurious. Your `<a>` tag is not closed and it's `href` attribute is not quoted. Same with your iframe tag. The parser you're using should tell you where it encountered the error. Fix it and then you'll be good to go.

If you want to parse *xml*, first you must ensure that it is [well formed XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML#Well-formedness_and_error-handling). Often, it's possible to do a little massaging to make an otherwise unparseable snippet something well formed so that you can use a standard parser.

Answer (score 0):

A quick visual inspection of your XML fragment, and two things jumped out at me re: your XML not being well formed:

- Your closing `<xyz>` element is missing it's slash: it should be `</xyz>`
- Your `<a>` and `<iframe>` elements are also not closed.